# Does exist any integer $n\geq 1$ satisfying $\varphi(12n)=\varphi(6n+5)$, where $\varphi(m)$ denotes the Euler's totient function?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, totient-function

We consider the Euler's totient function $\varphi(n)$ for integers $n\geq 1$. I was playing with the condition $$\varphi(12n)=\varphi(6n+a)\tag{1},$$ for different and simple (integer) values of $a$, when I wondered if one can to find some solution of the equation $$\varphi(12n)=\varphi(6n+5).\tag{2}$$

> **Question.** I don't know why for some integers like $a=1,2,3$ or $a=4$ one  can find solutions of $(1)$, but for different values likes than our equation $(2)$ it is difficult to find solutions. Do you have an idea about it? Specially I am asking if we can find some integer $n\geq 1$ of $$\varphi(12n)=\varphi(6n+5).$$
>   **Many thanks.**

**Computational fact.** There aren't solutions of $(2)$ in the interval $1\leq n\leq 10^7.\square$

I think that this problem $(2)$ isn't in the literature, any case if you know it, answer this question as a reference request and I try to find and read the literature to know if there exist some solution of $(2)$

Comment: Perhaps something in $\varphi(12n) = {{\varphi(12)\varphi(n)} \dot {gcd(n, 12)}\over{\varphi(gcd(n, 12))}} $ ; 2, 3 and 4 all divide 12 nicely; $

Comment: Are you saying that from your property is it possible to deduce that there aren't solutions? Many thanks @AhmedMasud

Comment: Not saying that but I would definitely look at that as a starting point... 6n+5 reminded me of Ramanujan's 5th order mock-$\theta$ expansions; not sure if there is a connection have to think about it

Comment: Then I'm sorry, my problem is that (sometimes) I've no a good intuition about if my questions are obvious. Many thanks for your attention @AhmedMasud

Comment: @user243301 The smallest solution (and the only upto $n=10^8$) is $$80\ 538\ 624$$ (See answer below)

Comment: The next solution is $$204\ 160\ 584$$

Comment: And the third is $$359\ 345\ 152$$

Comment: And if you want some bigger solutions (not necessarily consecutive ones), here are a few: $986659840$, $2820644204544$, $5390020614144$, $25538078912512$ (and I'm sure @Peter will notice the pattern I exploited to find them :-) ).

Comment: Many thanks @PeterKošinár

Comment: @PeterKošinár Could you elaborate on the pattern you exploited?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is at least one solution as this PARI/GP-program shows :

```
? for(n=1,10^8,if(eulerphi(12*n)==eulerphi(6*n+5),print(n)))
80538624
?
```

Upto $10^8$, there is apparently only one solution.

Comment: +1 for persistence!  I didn't bother to test it since the OP had already done it up to $10^7$.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, it's incredible. I am going to wait a week if there is more feedback before I am accepting an answer.. And feel free, when you want, in next week to add the table of known solutions of the equation, many thanks.